# json serialization ignore kotlin field anotation

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

Spring boot APP 2.2.0.RELEASE

Configuration by default (use Jackson)

*WebMvcConfigurer, objectMapper*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    fun objectMapperMvc(): ObjectMapper {
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        val javaTimeModule = JavaTimeModule()

        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules()
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule)

        return objectMapper
    }

    @Bean
    fun messageConverter(): MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
        return MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapperMvc())
    }

    override fun configureMessageConverters(converters: MutableList<HttpMessageConverter<*>>) {
        converters.add(messageConverter())
    }
}
```

*Rest service*

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = [ApplicationProperties.MOBILE_TEST_END_POINT])
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
class MobileTest {
    @RequestMapping(value = ["/gen-token"], method = [RequestMethod.POST],
            consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
            produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun createSessionToken(@RequestBody @Valid genToken: GenToken): SessionToken {

    return SessionToken(sDataSec = "23123")
}
```

*Entity*

```
@AllOpen
@NoArg
class SessionToken (
    @JsonProperty(required = true, value = "sDataSec")
    @NotNull
    val sDataSec: String)
```

*Result json*

{
   "sdataSec": "23123"
}

**Ignore property JsonProperty and created field with name 'sdataSec' != 'sDataSec' expected**

Second attempt, remove field creation from constructor

*Entity*

```
@AllOpen
@NoArg
class SessionToken {
    @JsonProperty(required = true, value = "sDataSec")
    @NotNull
    lateinit var sDataSec: String
```

}

*Result json*

{
    "sDataSec": "23123",
    "sdataSec": "23123",
}

**This work, but now we has dublicate field with 2 different name**

Comment: Are you using any naming strategy for Jackson mapping ?

Comment: Add objectMapper text code

Comment: I don't know is there any problem with the default naming strategy. You can try stictly set  name strategy,`objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE);` in objectMapperMvc() and check also properties file is there any configuration or not.

Comment: Field has  anotaton @JsonProperty (required = true, value = "sDataSec"). And this works if remove field creation from constructor.